# How do I set a minimum size using phpThumb class?

Tags: php, image

I have a problem with set a minimum size for my image.
How do I set a minimum size using phpThumb class ?

```
$phpThumb = new phpThumb();
$phpThumb->setParameter('w', 960);
$phpThumb->setParameter('y', 480);
```

I want minimum size for my Image a "w-960" and "y-480".